# Migrating Website from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: security, https, frontend

I have to migrate a website from HTTP to HTTPS and keep user experience unchanged (no warning popups). What would be the front end main points to be verified?

I realized I have to make sure all inclusions (CSS, images and JS) have to reference https content, but I'm still not sure about the a(link) href attribute and if there's anything I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to migrate to HTTPS](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oRXJUIttqQxuxmjj2tgYjj096IKw4Zcw6eAoIKWZ2oQ/preview?sle=true) is an excellent migration howto.  The steps are:

1. Get and install certificates
2. Enable HTTPS on your servers
3. Make intra-site URLs relative
4. Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
5. Turn on strict transport security and secure cookies

Between step 3 and step 4, run through [Qualys' best practices](https://www.ssllabs.com/projects/best-practices/) and [test your site](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).

Answer (score 2):

Updated Feb 02, 2016

Planning on moving to HTTPS? Here are 13 FAQs! visit https://plus.google.com/+JohnMueller/posts/PY1xCWbeDVC

I done of my website and works perfectly (it depends on the size of your site). My site is local business indexed (2,xxx) on google
 1. No effect on SEO Ranking
 2. No effect on link juice

Answer (score 0):

Related links will ref to https automatically. All absolute links have to ref to https, unless you configure your htaccess file to redirect all http traffic to https.